# javascript Countdown timer with weeks and months

Tags: javascript, countdown

I need a countdown script to calculate the difference between two dates, in months, weeks, and days.

I know about timespan.js and countdown.js, but those scripts only work with days. 
What script could I use for months and weeks?

preferable the dates are in the yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: https://github.com/icambron/moment-countdown

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: do you want the difference between two dates, or a countdown from now to a given date ?

Comment: A countdown to a given date from now indeed. Not in hours or less, just in days, weeks and months

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski I'd prefer less than three files ;)

Comment: doesn't countdown.js do what you want? from the demo I see here : http://countdownjs.org/demo.html , you can easily have the month count.

Comment: Countdown.js won't work for me :(
It keeps saying 'Countdown' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about moment.js? There is probably a 'months' feature?
https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=moment.js+difference+between+two+dates+in+months&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Check the console

http://jsfiddle.net/x9yL7xL7/

```
moment('2018-02-01 00:00:00');
```

Taken from: http://www.netengine.at/de/hilfe/wiki/wiki-detail/?wid=90